# Persist (save) Entity object with Foreign Key as a part of composite Primary Key (Spring Boot, Spring JPA) - throws error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pharmacy", schema = "master_relational_db")
public class Pharmacy {

    @Id @Column(name = "id_pharmacy", columnDefinition = "INT(3)") private Integer id;
    ... some other columns
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pharmacy", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Article> articles;
```

Above class represent pharmacy and it has simple integer id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article", schema = "master_relational_db")
public class Article {

    @EmbeddedId private ArticleId id;
    @Column(name ="name", length = 512, nullable = false) private String name;
    ... some other columns

    @MapsId("id_article_pharmacy")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="article_pharmacy_fk")
    private Pharmacy pharmacy;
```

The above class is a class that represents an article that belongs to a specific pharmacy. It has @ManyToOne relationship with pharmacy, and that foreign key is also part of the article's embedded (ArticleId) primary key.

```
@Embeddable
public class ArticleId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id_article")
    private Integer idArticle;

    @Column(name = "id_article_pharmacy")
    private Integer idPharmacy; //this is filled with foreign key (this is id of linked pharmacy)

    public ArticleId(Integer idArticle, Integer idPharmacy){
        this.idArticle = idArticle;
        this.idPharmacy = idPharmacy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof ArticleId)) return false;
        ArticleId that = (ArticleId) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getIdPharmacy(), that.getIdPharmacy()) &&
                Objects.equals(getIdArticle(), that.getIdArticle());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getIdArticle(), getIdPharmacy());
    }
}
```

Above class represent id for article, it has some integer article id (id_article) and pharmacy id that is also a foreign key representing ManyToOne relationship with pharmacy.
I run the above code, and it creates tables in the database just as I wanted. I populate the pharmacy table with some data, but when I want to create a new article and link it with some pharmacy problem appears. Down is code for adding a new article, this code is part of my service (@Service) method for adding new article:

```
    @Transactional
    public void addArticle() throws SQLException {

       Article toSave = new Article(...constructor for setting fields that are not pk or fk);

            Pharmacy ap = pharmacyRepository.findById(idOfPharmacy).get(); //we get pharmacy //with some id that we want to link this new article with.
//I debug this code and findById returns wanted pharmacy from DB.
            

            ArticleId id = new ArticleId(10, ap.getId());//we create ArticleId with id_article = 10 and id_article_pharmacy = (id of ap object (id of pharmacy that we get from findById method))

            toSave.setId(id);//we set id for article
            toSave.setPharmacy(ap);//we set pharmacy for article (foreign key - should be same as id_article_pharmacy from AricleId)
            System.out.println("ID [Id of pharmacy is: " +toSave.getId().getIdPharmacy() + " | id of article is : "
                    +toSave.getId().getIdArticle() + "] fk pharmacy name is: " + toSave.getPharmacy().getName()); // this is what i get here when i run it : ID [Id of pharmacy is: 1 | id of article is : 1] fk pharmacy name is: Pharmacy BENU - so all data is linked
            //ap.addArticle(toSave);
            articleRepository.save(toSave); //we use repository that extends CrudRepository to save article in db.

    }
```

when i hit this service i get this error : java.sql.SQLException: Field 'article_pharmacy_fk' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21] ........... and so on
Can someone help me i tried everythig? :/

..... SOLUTION ....
Problem was in definition of my ArticleId. I didn't need to define @Column antotation for idPharmacy (cuz i don't want to create new column for that , i want to reference it). So i deleted that @Column anotation. I also needed to replace @MapsId("id_article_pharmacy") with @MapsId("idPharmacy"). That is how i solved the problem.

Comment: You have to add article to pharmacy `ap.getArticles().add(toSave)`;

Comment: I tried it but i comment it in this example (ap.addArticle(toSave)). When i uncomment this i get other error : javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Article with id ArticleId@3e1

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Article with id ArticleId@3e1

Comment: I think hibernate tries to find that article in db before he tries to link it in pharmacy (ap.addArticle(toSave)) and because i haven't save it yet, he can not find it.

Comment: What's the purpose of using the`@EmbeddedId` object as **id** instead of `@Id @Column(name = "id_article") private Integer idArticle`? If column `article`.`id_article` is unique use it as **id**, if not - why it has such a name?

Comment: Cuz i want my key to be composite e.g. it has 2 column that are part of primary key: id_article and id_article_pharmacy. Second one (id_article_pharmacy) is foreign key, it is primary key of Pharmacy that is linked to this Article.

Comment: As far as I kniow `@MapsId("id_article_pharmacy")` have to have `ArticleId` field name as a parameter(`idPharmacy`) . `id_article_pharmacy` is database column name.

Comment: That is not an issue it works fine also with column name. I know it because i also generate db scheme with this code and the model is fine.

Comment: You were right @alexvaluiskyi, problem was in Column anotation for idPharmacy in ArticleId and MapsId also needed to be replaced with MapsId(idPharmacy). Thanks for the hint!